# Loop and grep function in R

Tags: r

I have a variable called "attendance" that that tracks daily attendance of a person. If it contains an "a" then the person attended the first day, "b" if the person attended the second day, all the way til "e" if the person attended the fifth day. So some people's attendance looks like "abc" or "cde" or "ace" if they attended first three days, last three days, or first/third/last days, respectively.

Now I want to create a variable "day_1" that equals 1 if "attendance" contains "a" and 0 otherwise. Then a variable "day_2" that equals 2 if "attendance" contains "b" and 0 otherwise. And so on until "day_5"

I have tried using the grep function to do it manually. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    test <- data.frame(hhid = c(1:5),attendance=c("abc","bcd","d","ec","ade"))
    test$day_1 <- 0
    test$day_2 <- 0
    test$day_3 <- 0
    test$day_1[grep("a", test$attendance, "day_1")] <- "1"
    test$day_2[grep("b", test$attendance, "day_2")] <- "1"
    test$day_3[grep("c", test$attendance, "day_3")] <- "1"
```

Is there a faster way of doing it in R?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please a share a sample reproduciblesmall data such that we can work on them directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't shared any sample data to work on, I created a sample vector to give you an idea.

```
test <- data.frame(hhid = c(1:5),attendance=c("abc","bcd","d","ec","ade"))
b = as.list(letters[1:5])

abc <- function(i){
  ifelse(grepl(b[[i]], test$attendance),1,0) 
}
m=sapply(seq_along(b), abc)
colnames(m)=paste("day",1:5,sep="_")
test <- cbind(test,m)
```

Comment: Added an example now.

Comment: did you give a try to the solution shared?! Ask specific question if you have any  based on the answer

Comment: edited my answer ,accommodating your example! Check if this answers your question!

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly! Thanks. Sorry am just new so can you please help explain why we need the second row of the code and also what does seq_along(b) do?

Comment: Sure, b contains the first five alphabets which we are trying to search for in the data$attendance. So b has 5 elements. seq_along(b) gives you the index. I.e. the position index of that element. Try printing seq_along(b) in the console and you will get an idea. Another help would be to debug(abc) so that you get to know what is happening in each iteration of sapply()

Comment: @imprela got it?!

Comment: This is an old post, but is there a `data.table` solution for this?